# Bash code problem in accessing directories and its files

Tags: linux, bash

[image: code]

I am new in bash, and using online bash compiler, I am trying to go to access every directory and the file in it in a loop. But every time it is showing the directory does not exist. What is the correct syntax to create and access the directory in online bash compiler like replit?

```
#!/bin/bash
for I in new, new1
  do
    cp /fileName $1
  done

Output:

cp: cannot stat 'fileName': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'fileName': No such file or directory
```

Comment: you should add a sample example of what you are trying to do

Comment: Show the code you've tried so far?

Comment: ok just a minute

Comment: I have attached the picture to the question.. please have a look at that. There I have tried to copy a file named "fileName" to the the directories.

Comment: `for i in new new1; do echo cp filename "$i"; done` No need for the `,` to separate the elements that you're looping through, Also the `/` means the parent directory on a Unix/Linux directory tree, The `echo` is there to show you what might have been...

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: How I will write now if I want to loop through all the files present in all the directories?@Jetchisel

Comment: Either use `globstar`s shell option from `bash` or use `find`. I can't do it right now, hopefully someone can answer you. Mean while search this forum , there are a lot of entries/question like yours.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you prefix `fileName` with `/`, so it's expecting one in the root directory (of the operating system), not a file *relative* to where the program is being run, but literally a file at `/fileName`

You then also use `$I` as the loop variable, but later try to refer to `$1` when they should be the same

you almost-certainly want a form like

```sh
for path in new new1; do
   cp fileName "$path/"
done
```